# How do I create an HTML element that remains on the page and is unaffected by scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a button that remains on the screen, no matter how much we scroll through the page, like the button is stuck on the display. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Recommended read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Please show what you tried. Post some code. Consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**absolute**

Indicates that the element is absolutely positioned, while other elements are displayed on the web page as if there was absolutely no positioned element. The position of the element is set by the left, top, right, and bottom properties, and the position property of the parent element also affects the position. So, if the parent value of position is set to static or there is no parent, then the coordinates are counted from the edge of the browser window. If the parent's position value is set to fixed, relative or absolute, then the coordinates are counted from the edge of the parent element.

**fixed**

In its effect, this value is close to absolute, but unlike it, it is tied to the point indicated on the left, top, right, and bottom properties of the screen and does not change its position when scrolling through a web page. The Firefox browser does not display scrollbars at all if the position of the element is fixed and it does not fit entirely into the browser window. Although Opera bars show scrollbars, they do not affect the position of an element.

**relative**

The position of the element is set relative to its original location. Adding the left, top, right, and bottom properties changes the position of the element and shifts it in one direction or another from the original location.

**static**

Items are displayed as usual. Using the left, top, right, and bottom properties does not produce any results.

**inherit**

Inherits the meaning of the parent.

In your case, 'fixed' should work

HTML:

```
<div class="fix_block">Fixed block</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fix_block {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 100px; 
    left: 30px; 
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed;` on the element. You can then set its location by setting some combination of top, right, bottom, or left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS position property to achieve this, in you case the property you need is `position:fixed;`

Using this property you can position an element relative to the view port of the browser, and it will always stay in the same place even if the page is scrolled.
So simply put if you have a html element which you want to fix position for just 
select it in css and give it `position:fixed;` and respective left, right, top, bottom values to align it.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed_div">I am fixed!</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed_div {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 40%; 
    left: 40%; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score -1):

Use the FIXED position
for example: when you have a

```
   <div class:"fixed-btn"> Fixed button </div>
```

Your Css Should be like:

```
 .fixed-btn{
       position:fixed;
       top:100px;
       left:0px;
       baground:#fff;
       padding:5px;
    }
```

Try it..

Comment: Although what you've posted would solve the problem, (ignoring the capital P in position: fixed), it doesn't really answer the question; you've not explained to them have to set an element so it doesn't move, you've explained to them how to apply and css class, that in this case, happens to have a rule that sets the position to fixed.